# How to add custom form on cash on delivery payment method using layout in checkout_index_index.xml Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, layout, payment-methods, payment, checkout-page

I want to add form in cash on delivery payment method only on checkout page Magento 2. I want to add it using layout checkout_index_index.xml.

Can anyone please tell me how to add form using layout file on checkout page Magento 2?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-cash-on-delivery-payment-method-magento-2.html

Comment: I need to add dynamic content on cash on delivery payment method

Answer (score 1):

You may create a custom module and override few js file for this customisation as describe below.

I assume you custom module name is **Company_CodForm**.

**Note:**

In this COD Form module I created two form field.That are "**codfield1**" and "**codfield2**". codfield1 is text input and codfield2 is dropdown.
I also write js code (app/code/Company/CodForm/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method.js) accordingly. Please change this js file as per your custom COD form fields.

**step 1)** *Create **requirejs-config.js** under YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/view/*

File:  **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/view/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
           'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/offline-payments': 'Company_CodForm/js/view/payment/offline-payments'         
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2)** Create **offline-payments.js** under *YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment*

File: **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/offline-payments.js**

/

```
**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'checkmo',
                component: 'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/checkmo-method'
            },
            {
               type: 'banktransfer',
               component: 'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/banktransfer-method'
            },
            {
                type: 'cashondelivery',
                component: 'Company_CodForm/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method'
            },
            {
                type: 'purchaseorder',
                component: 'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/purchaseorder-method'
            }
        );
        /** Add view logic here if needed */
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

**step 3:** Create **cashondelivery-method.js** under **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer**

File : ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method.js***

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'jquery'
    ],
    function (ko, Component,$) {
        'use strict';

         var optionsList = ko.observableArray();  
         var codOption = function(name, id) {
              this.name = name;
              this.id = id;
         };

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'MagePritam_CodForm/payment/codForm'
            },
             initialize: function(){
                 this._super(); 
                 this.populateOptionsList();             
                 return this;
             },            
            optionsList: optionsList,            
            getData: function() {
                return {
                    'method': this.item.method,
                    'additional_data': {
                        'codfield1': $('#cashondelivery_codfield1').val(),
                        'codfield2': $('#cashondelivery_codfield2').val()
                    }
                };
            },
            /**
             * Get value of instruction field.
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getInstructions: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
            },
            populateOptionsList: function(){
                 var self =  this;                
                 this.optionsList([
                     new codOption('Cash','cashcodpayment'),                     
                     new codOption('Credit/Debit Card','cardcodpayment')                     
                 ]);

             }  

        });
    }
);
```

**step 4)** Create template file **codForm.html** under  **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/view/frontend/web/template**

File : ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/view/frontend/web/template/codForm.html***

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" />
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>   
    <fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}"> 
    <div class="field _required">
        <label data-bind="attr: {for: getCode() + '_codfield1'}" class="label">
            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'COD Custom Field 1'--><!-- /ko --></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input data-validate="{'required-entry':true}" type="text" name="payment[codfield1]" class="input-text" value=""
                   data-bind="attr: {
                                    id: getCode() + '_codfield1',
                                    title: $t('COD Field'),
                                    'data-container': getCode() + '-codfield1',
                                    'data-validate': JSON.stringify({'required':true})},
                                    valueUpdate: 'keyup' "/>
        </div>

        <div class="control">
             <select  data-validate="{'required-entry':true}" 
                    data-bind="attr: {
                       id: getCode() + '_codfield2',
                      },
                      options: optionsList(),
                      optionsText: 'name',
                      optionsValue:'id',
                     optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
             </select>   
        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>      
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {'title': $t('Place Order')},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**step 5)** Create observer file **SaveCodInfo.php** under   ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/Observer*** 
to save the COD custom field data in order payment table .

File : ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/Observer/SaveCodInfo.php***

```
<?php

namespace Company\CodForm\Observer;

use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;

/**
 * Class SavePoNumberToOrderObserver
 */
class SaveCodInfo extends AbstractDataAssignObserver
{
    const CODE_FIELD_1 = 'codfield1';
    const CODE_FIELD_2 = 'codfield2';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $additionalInformationList = [
        self::CODE_FIELD_1,
        self::CODE_FIELD_2
    ];


    protected $logger;


    public function __construct(

      \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger

      ) {

        $this->logger = $logger;

    }
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $this->readDataArgument($observer);
        $additionalData = $data->getData(PaymentInterface::KEY_ADDITIONAL_DATA);
        if (!is_array($additionalData)) {
            return;
        }


        $this->logger->info("COD Form Log additionalData",$additionalData);


        $paymentInfo = $this->readPaymentModelArgument($observer);

        foreach ($this->additionalInformationList as $additionalInformationKey) {
            if (isset($additionalData[$additionalInformationKey])) {
                $paymentInfo->setData(
                    $additionalInformationKey,
                    $additionalData[$additionalInformationKey]
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 6)** Create **events.xml** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/etc***

File :  ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/CodForm/etc/events.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_assign_data">
        <observer name="save_codform_infos" instance="Company\CodForm\Observer\SaveCodInfo"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

:: Demo ::

[image]

Comment: Can i add custom dropdown for selected payment methods without overriding template file. By playing with js layout ?

Comment: What is your particular requirement ? please explain.

Comment: How can we use Mobile OTP verification on the selection of cash on the delivery method? @PritamInfo24

Comment: Hello @Utsav.
You can use a custom field name "cod_otp". Generate the OTP and save that is database [saving custom filed for COD already ] with Quote ID. Now send the OTP to customer via SMS and open a New Input Box to enter the OTP. Now Put a extra button name "validate OTP" and do check the entered OTP with the save once . Also use the Quote ID while validating the OTP

Comment: I followed this answer and try to create the mobile verification code. That code working correctly. but now the payment method is updating every second I don't know why? any idea?